# Rails.cache.read following a Rails.cache.increment does not give correct value

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, caching, memcached

Using Rails 3 with memcachestore and the memcache-client gem.

Local memcache on a macbook-pro or memcache servers on the staging environment.

When I do a

```
Rails.cache.increment(key, 1)
```

followed very quickly (w/in a few lines) by a

```
Rails.cache.read(key, :raw => true)
```

I get my original value.  If it sits for a second and then I call read (or in the console), I get the correctly incremented value.

As my work around, I'm using the returned value from the increment call, but this doesn't seem like it should be happening.

Any ideas?

Comment: Sounds like this an event driven issue.  You aren't using EventMachine are you?

Answer (score 0):

This problem is described in a blog post
  http://thomasmango.com/2009/06/25/a-better-rails-cache-increment/

and the suggested fix is:

```
class Util::Cache
  def self.increment(key, amount = 1)
    if (value = Rails.cache.read(key)).nil?
      Rails.cache.write(key, (value = amount))
    else
      Rails.cache.write(key, (value = value + amount))
    end

    return value
  end

  def self.decrement(key, amount = 1)
    if (value = Rails.cache.read(key)).nil?
      value = 0
    else
      Rails.cache.write(key, (value = value - amount))
    end

    return value
  end
end
```